# Can I take a boxed bicycle from Trabzon to the Georgian border, and then Batumi?

Tags: luggage, turkey, bicycles, georgia-country

1. Is there a reasonably priced coach from Trabzon to Batumi, where I could place my bicycle (which is worth less than €100 and would be in a cardboard box with the front wheel removed) in the luggage bay?
2. If not, do you think a minibus/marschrutka driver would allow me to place such a large box in the back of the minibus for the considerable distance from Trabzon to Georgia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metro Georgia runs a bus from Batumi to Trabzon (continuing to Istanbul). I paid GEL 80 a month or so ago. It's a full-size bus with a luggage bay and I doubt a bike would be an issue (you can ask). There should be a bus going in the opposite direction.

[www.metrogeorgia.ge](http://www.metrogeorgia.ge)

I didn't see any other long distance bus options for Trabzon at the Batumi station outside of town.

The border crossing takes quite a bit of time and you do have to haul *all* your luggage on and off the bus and through customs and immigration twice (outgoing and incoming- a very short bus ride apart) so without a cart or something that might be challenging.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think they would want to look inside the box at customs? (ie, do I need to bother taping it up?)

Comment: I didn't see much, if any, inspection of baggage, even for some fairly dodgy-looking characters, but I was going in the opposite direction.